# How to specify ticks locations in chart.js?

Tags: charts, location, chart.js

I am looking for a way to manually specify x/y ticks locations on a `chart.js` chart, an equivalent of matplotlib's [matplotlib.pyplot.xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html). The documentation explains how to [create custom tick formats](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats), but this works on automatically calculated tick locations. How can I specify the ticks locations?

This is the config that I am using:

```js
var config = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            data: [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 5, y: 3}, {x: 6, y: 4}],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "#1f77b4",
        }],
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                distribution: 'series',
                ticks: {
                    min: 0.,
                    max: 7.,
                },
            }]
        },
    },
}
```

which produces this file:
[image: chart]

I would like to specify xticks locations, e.g. `[0., 3.5, 5.7, 6.1]`, so that the plot would look more like (not taking into account grid lines and smooth plot line):

[image: mpl]

Comment: please post the code you already have, possibly with a picture of expected result.

Comment: @uminder I edited my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently with **Chart.js v3**, the accpted solution no longer works as expected. Trying `afterBuildTicks` as suggested by [b1000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10734962/b1000) in his comment, it also didn't work.

To make it work with `afterBuildTicks`, you need to map the number values into objects that have the property `value` each (`[{ value: 0 }, { value: 3.5 }, ... ]`). This can be done as follows:

```
afterBuildTicks: axis => axis.ticks = [0, 3.5, 5.7, 6.1].map(v => ({ value: v }))
```

Please take a look at below runnable sample:

```js
new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 5, y: 3}, {x: 6, y: 4}],
      showLine : true,
      borderColor: '#1f77b4',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {    
        min: 0,
        afterBuildTicks: axis => axis.ticks = [0, 3.5, 5.7, 6.1].map(v => ({ value: v })) 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

For not drawing grid lines on the chart, you need to add the following to your axes as described at [Grid Line Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration).

```
gridLines: {
  drawOnChartArea: false 
}
```

In order to obtain the ticks at the desired position only, you would define `xAxis.ticks` as shown below and documented at [Tick Option](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#tick-options) and [Creating Custom Tick Formats](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats).

```
ticks: {
  ...       
  stepSize: 0.1,
  autoSkip: false,
  callback: value => [0, 3.5, 5.7, 6.1].includes(value) ? value : undefined,
  maxRotation: 0
},
```

Finally, to obtain a straight line between the data points, define `lineTension: 0` on your dataset as explained at [Line Styling](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling).

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
var config = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 5, y: 3}, {x: 6, y: 4}],
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      borderColor: "#1f77b4",
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
          min: 0.,
          max: 7.,          
          stepSize: 0.1,
          autoSkip: false,
          callback: value => [0, 3.5, 5.7, 6.1].includes(value) ? value : undefined,
          maxRotation: 0
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          showLabelBackdrop: true
        }, 
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }]
    },
  },
};

new Chart('line-chart', config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @uminder! What do you think of overwriting `options.scales.xAxes[0].afterBuildTicks`, like `afterBuildTicks: function(axis, ticks) {return [0, 3.5, 5.7, 6.1];}`? This way I'm not relying on ticks locations being multiples of `stepSize`.

Comment: I never used `afterBuildTicks` but your idea sounds good, give it a try.

Comment: thanks @b1000, I had the same problem and since in my chart x axis range is too large, setting step size is not an option. your idea worked like a charm!

Comment: the sample code doesn't seem to work with version 3.5

Comment: @uwe: I posted a new answer that illustrates how it can be done with `Chart.js v3`.